# Spring's HibernateTemplate return value

Tags: hibernate, spring, stored-procedures

I have a mySQL stored procedure which does various calculations in my DB and returns the following rowset:

```
ID integer, DISTANCE float, RADIUS float
```

These columns are not mapped to any Pojo, and I would like to parse them (like in JDBC)
I currently use `HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery()` to run my stored procedure, however this function returns a List, which is supposed to be List of a mapped Pojo. (in all the example I saw) 
But in my case it's the result set is not related to pojos, how do I return a rowset with this configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a query returns scalars, the list returned by Hibernate contains arrays of Objects. So you should have a `List<Object[]>`, each `Object[]` containing three elements:

- an Integer (ID)
- a Float (distance)
- a Float (radius)